# Getting rid of frame and axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have done some research, but every solution I found didn't work for what comes with 'Anaconda-2.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh'... Can someone tell me how to get rid of the frame and the axis labels?

```
boros = GeoDataFrame.from_file('nybb/nybb.shp') 
boros.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: It may help to show what you have tried (even though it didn't work), and associated error messages (if any).  Note:  added tag for `matplotlib` as that is the library underlying pandas plots.

Comment: Based on the documentation for `.plot()` it looks like it's a wrapper for `pandas.DataFrame.plot`, which allows you to declare **xticks** and **yticks** parameters. You will need to set these.

Comment: Thanks, for replying. I ended up not using a shape file, zooming into Basemap and reading Data from SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to remove spines and tick labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
y = 2*np.sin(x)

ax.plot(x, y) 

ax.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.grid('off')

[ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False) for spine in ax.spines]

ax.set_xticklabels([]);
ax.set_yticklabels([]);

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that when you call `.plot()` you need to pass a reference to axes object where the plot will be placed, like so `.plot(ax=ax)`.

If you do not have a variable referring to the axes object you could access current axes with `plt.gca()`.